# Group By With Rollup and Count(Distinct)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct, rollup

I'm running into a slight issue with using a `Group By With Rollup` while getting a `Count` of a `Distinct`.

The issue is that the `Rollup` summary is only the total count of `Distinct` values across all groupings, rather than a summary of all groupings.

Here's a test scenario to illustrate what I mean:

```
Create Table #Test
(
    GroupId Int Not Null,
    Value   Int Not Null
)

Insert  #Test (GroupId, Value)
Values  (1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),(1, 5),(1, 1),
        (2, 1),(2, 6),(2, 7),(2, 5),(2, 7),(2, 5),
        (3, 9),(3, 10),(3, 11),(3, 4),(3, 5),(3, 7),(3, 8),(3, 5),(3, 7),(3, 8)
```

For this particular table, if I run this query:

```
Select  Case When Grouping(GroupId) = 1 Then 'Total:' Else Str(GroupId) End As GroupId, 
        Count(Distinct Value) Count
From    #Test
Group By GroupId With Rollup
Order By Grouping(GroupId), GroupId
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
GroupId Count
-------------
1       5
2       4
3       7
Total:  11
```

My expected result for the Total row would be 16, but instead I'm only getting 11 -- which is the total number of `Distinct` Values among all groups.

Removing the `Distinct` from the query does show the expected results for that `Rollup`:

```
Select  Case When Grouping(GroupId) = 1 Then 'Total:' Else Str(GroupId) End As GroupId, 
        Count(Value) Count
From    #Test
Group By GroupId With Rollup
Order By Grouping(GroupId), GroupId
```

Which yields these results:

```
GroupId Count
-------------
1       7
2       6
3       10
Total:  23
```

Which summarizes the groups as expected.

My question is: is this normal for a `Rollup` on a `Count Distinct`?  Is there some other `Rollup`-like option to use for the `Grouping` to get 16 displayed rather than 11 in the example above?

Comment: You want DISTINCT Results in the SELECT but all values in the last rollup row?

Comment: I'm wanting a distinct count for each group, and a summary of all groups.  The groups are showing the counts correctly, but I would want the rollup row to show the the total among all of the groups (e.g., showing 16, rather than 11).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get what you want by nesting the queries and using a trick:

```
select (Case When Grouping(GroupId) = 1 Then 'Total:' Else Str(GroupId) End) as GroupId, 
       Sum(Count) as Count
from (Select GroupId, 
             Count(Distinct Value) as Count
      From  #Test
      Group By GroupId
     ) t
Group By GroupId With Rollup
Order By Grouping(GroupId), GroupId;
```

The second `group by` doesn't logically do an aggregation, because there is only one row per group.  It is just there for getting the value you want in the `rollup`.

Comment: Ah - I was hoping to achieve this without nesting.  Any idea why `Rollup` behaves this way?

Comment: @Siyual . . . The rollup is on `count(distinct)`.  Many people would consider this behavior to be a good thing.  The sum of distinct counts is not the same as the count distinct of the union of things.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  So, `Rollup` essentially applies the same aggregation to all of the groups as a whole, rather than applying the same aggregation to the results of each group.  That makes sense why a `Count(Distinct)` would behave that way.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Siyual . . . Think about what should happen for a `min()` or `max()` or `avg()` and it will make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

Create the test data:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    GroupId Int Not Null,
    Value   Int Not Null
)

Insert  @Test 
(GroupId, Value)
Values  (1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),(1, 5),(1, 1),
        (2, 1),(2, 6),(2, 7),(2, 5),(2, 7),(2, 5),
        (3, 9),(3, 10),(3, 11),(3, 4),(3, 5),(3, 7),(3, 8),(3, 5),(3, 7),(3, 8)
```

I changed the third column to group distinct by group id AND value

```
Select  Case When Grouping(GroupId) = 1 Then 'Total:' Else Str(GroupId) End As GroupId, 
       Count(DISTINCT Value) As Count,
        Count(Value) AS Count2,
        Count(DISTINCT (GroupId * 10) + Value) AS Count3
From    @Test
Group By GroupId With Rollup
Order By Grouping(GroupId), GroupId
```

Here is the output:

```
GroupId Count Count2 Count3
1       5     7      5
2       4     6      4
3       7     10     7
Total:  11    23     16
```